# Bash: An IF statement returns unexpected value, can you find the reason?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nrpe, xinetd

I've wrote a script which automatically downloads and installs Nagios NRPE on CentOS machines.
The relevant portion of the script is:

```
read -r -p "How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon " DMN
        if [ "DMN" = "x" -o "DMN" = "X" ];
                then
            DMNMODE="xinetd"
                        cat << EOF > $XINETDFILE
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = $NRPEPORT
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = $NGUSER 
        group           = $NGGROUP
        server          = /usr/sbin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c $NRPECFG --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 $NAGIOSSRV
}
EOF
            /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
        elif [ "DMN" = "d" -o "DMN" = "D" ];
                    then 
                chkconfig nrpe on ; $NRPESVC start
                DMNMODE="daemon"

    fi
function CheckInstMode {
                                if [ "DMNMODE" = "daemon" ];
                                        then
                        $NRPESVC restart
                    else
                        $XINETDSVC restart
                                fi
}
read -r -p "Would you like to pull NRPE plugins from Nagios server? [y/n]" ANS1
        if [ $ANS1 = "y" ];
                then
                        if [ $ARCH = "64" -a $NGSARCH = "64" ] ;
                        then scp root@$NAGIOSSRV:$NGPLUGINS64/* $NGPLUGINS64/
                        chown -R $NGUSER.$NGGROUP $NGPLUGINS64
            CheckInstMode
                        elif [ "$ARCH" = "64" -a "$NGSARCH" = "32" ] ;
                        then scp root@$NAGIOSSRV:$NGPLUGINS32/* $NGPLUGINS64/
                        chown -R $NGUSER.$NGGROUP $NGPLUGINS64
            CheckInstMode
                        elif [ "$ARCH" = "32" -a "$NGSARCH" = "32" ] ;
                        then scp root@$NAGIOSSRV:$NGPLUGINS32/* $NGPLUGINS32/
                        chown -R $NGUSER.$NGGROUP $NGPLUGINS32
            CheckInstMode
                        elif [ "$ARCH" = "32" -a  "$NGSARCH" = "64" ] ;
                        then scp root@$NAGIOSSRV:$NGPLUGINS64/* $NGPLUGINS32/
                        chown -R $NGUSER.$NGGROUP $NGPLUGINS32
            CheckInstMode
                        fi
        fi
```

The idea behind the function is to check which installation mode was chosen and restart `/etc/init.d/xinetd` if Xinetd was chosen or restart `/etc/init.d/nrpe` if NRPE was chosen.
I've ran the script in debug mode (`sh -x script`) and this is the output:

```
+ case $ARCH in
+ echo 'Configuring /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg'
Configuring /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
+ cat
+ echo 'Adding nagios user to /etc/sudoers'
Adding nagios user to /etc/sudoers
+ echo 'Defaults:nagios !requiretty'
+ echo 'nagios ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/*'
+ echo 'Setting ownership of nagios and nagios plugins folders to nagios user'
Setting ownership of nagios and nagios plugins folders to nagios user
+ chown -R nagios.nagios /etc/nagios
+ chown -R nagios.nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins
+ read -r -p 'How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon ' DMN
How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon x
+ '[' DMN = x -o DMN = X ']'
+ '[' DMN = d -o DMN = D ']'
+ read -r -p 'Would you like to pull NRPE plugins from Nagios server? [y/n]' ANS1
Would you like to pull NRPE plugins from Nagios server? [y/n]y
+ '[' y = y ']'
+ '[' 64 = 64 -a 64 = 64 ']'
+ scp 'root@IP:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/*' /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/
1                                             100%   71     0.1KB/s   00:00    
Back-check_services.pl                        100% 2485     2.4KB/s   00:00    
cacticpu.sh                                   100%  189     0.2KB/s   00:00    
check_apt                                     100%   99KB  99.4KB/s   00:00    
check_breeze                                  100% 2253     2.2KB/s   00:00    
check_by_ssh                                  100%   41KB  40.6KB/s   00:00    
check_clamd                                   100%   46KB  46.5KB/s   00:00    
+ chown -R nagios.nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins
+ CheckInstMode
+ '[' DMNMODE = daemon ']'
+ /etc/init.d/nrpe restart
Shutting down nrpe:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting nrpe:                                             [  OK  ]
+ stat --format=%Y /etc/passwd
+ chmod +x /usr/local/share/applications/file
+ read -r -p 'Would you like to test NRPE? [y/n]' ANS2
Would you like to test NRPE? [y/n]
```

As you can see the `DMNMODE` variable which is expected to be `xinetd` is `daemon` instead, even though my input for the question of xinetd or daemon was "x".
This causes the script to restart `nrpe` even if `xinetd` was selected, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit #1:
I still get an unexpected result from variable `$DMNMODE`, Here's the debug run:

```
How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon x
+ [[ x = [Xx] ]]
+ DMNMODE=xinetd
+ cat
+ /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
Stopping xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
+ read -r -p 'Would you like to pull NRPE plugins from Nagios server? [y/n]' ANS1
Would you like to pull NRPE plugins from Nagios server? [y/n]y
+ '[' y = y ']'
+ '[' 64 = 64 -a 64 = 64 ']'
+ scp 'root@IP:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/*' /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/
1                                             100%   71     0.1KB/s   00:00    
Back-check_services.pl                        100% 2485     2.4KB/s   00:00    
cacticpu.sh                                   100%  189     0.2KB/s   00:00    
check_apt                                     100%   99KB  99.4KB/s   00:00    
negate                                        100%   30KB  29.7KB/s   00:00    
plugins.pm                                    100% 1939     1.9KB/s   00:00    
+ chown -R nagios.nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins
+ CheckInstMode
+ '[' xinetd = daemon ']'
+ /etc/init.d/nrpe restart
Shutting down nrpe:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting nrpe:                                             [  OK  ]
+ stat --format=%Y /etc/passwd
+ chmod +x /usr/local/share/applications/file
+ read -r -p 'Would you like to test NRPE? [y/n]' ANS2
```

My question is... Why does the function return the wrong value? if you scroll up you can see that I typed X in the question which means that `DMNMODE` variable is set to `xinetd` and not `nrpe`... can you try and find the problem please?

Your help is much appreciated!
Itai

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$DMN` variable references are missing `$` signs.

```
if [ "$DMN" = "x" -o "$DMN" = "X" ];
```

Comment: In `if [ "DMNMODE" = "daemon" ];` a `$` is missing too.

Comment: Since you are using other `bash`-specific features (`read -p`), you can simply use `if [[ $DMN = [Xx] ]];` instead. At the very least, don't use the obsolete `-o` primary; use `[ "$DMN" = "x" ] || [ "$DMN" = "X" ]` instead.

Comment: Can you please check Edit #1? Thanks!

Comment: In a nutshell, you should never use `-o`. `||` can be used inside `[[...]]`, but otherwise you should use multiple calls to `[`.